# Why does not work when an animate css class is added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animate.css

When the class is added, it disappears for a moment. I do not know why

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrak4gc4/26/)

```
var i = 0;
function hello () {
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML += "<li id= '"+ i +"'>hello'"   + i +"'</li>";
$('#' + i).addClass('animated bounceInUp');
    if (i < 5) {
        setTimeout(hello, 5000);
    }
    i++;
}
hello();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You need to use jQuery or javasript syntaxes purely.Try not to mix them.

2.Add class to the first line of code itself and remove the second line to make your code shorter.

Do like below:-

```
var i=0;
function hello () {
  $('#demo').append("<li id= '"+ i +"' class='animated bounceInUp'>hello'" + i +"'</li>");
  if (i < 5) {
    setTimeout(hello, 5000);
  }
  i++;
}
hello();
```

***Working snippet:-***

```js
var i=0;
function hello () {
  $('#demo').append("<li id= '"+ i +"' class='animated bounceInUp'>hello'" + i +"'</li>");
  if (i < 5) {
     setTimeout(hello, 5000);
  }
  i++;
}
hello();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css@3.5.2/animate.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id = "demo" style="position: fixed;bottom:0" ></ul>
```

Working fiddle:- https://jsfiddle.net/Louuopk1/

Comment: what different between "+=" and "append" ?

Comment: in your code context both are doing same. only difference is the other one is jquery method.